# Edittext inside TableRow dimension is changing

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, tablelayout

I am applying round corners and changing the background color of my Edittext inside Tablelayout but `once` I apply the round corner my Edditetext changes it's dimensions and affects other TableRows. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_reset"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_row1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Price for 20 Minutes Visition"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_column="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subtotal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subtotal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/tv_subtotal_amount"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_column="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Coupon_code"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Coupon Code"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <EditText
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_coupon"
                />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

here is my edi_text_coupon.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I noticed a few issues. 
Updated your `EditText` to use `android:layout_width="0dp"`
On your table rows you need set `android:weightSum`
Your edit text dimension are going to change because you set a custom background on it.  

I would suggest using a `RelativeLayout` over the `TableLayout` with `LinearLayouts` with `weightsum`.

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to apply the round corner without having the dimensions to change. I tried to change the layout_width and weightSum to what you suggested but still doesn't work. :(

Comment: @NaNav can you add a before and after screen shot of the issue